# Is "sich einverstanden erklären" proper German?

Tags: translation, word-usage, usage, verb-usage

I am writing a translation for a cookie agreement text. I am quite sure my current text will bring the message across but I'm not sure if this 100% proper German.

This is the original English text:

> This site uses cookies in order to keep track of your language and other settings. No personal information will be stored!
> By using this page you agree with these terms.
> To dismiss this message click here!

This is my attempt to translate it:

> Diese Seite verwendet Cookies, um Einstellungen wie Sprache speichern zu können. Es werden keine persönlichen Daten gespeichert.
> Mit der Nutzung dieser Seite erklären Sie sich mit der Verwendung von Cookies einverstanden.
> Um diese Nachricht zu schließen, klicken Sie bitte hier.

I would apprechiate any improvements on any of these two texts.

Comment: OT: I see these messages everywhere lately, but I doubt they’re legally relevant in any German-speaking jurisdiction unless the user can opt out of cookies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good job! I have but one comment.

> um Einstellungen wie Sprache speichern zu können

This is not clear; it could mean "save settings and language". Proposal:

> um Einstellungen wie etwa die verwendete Sprache speichern zu können

Or closer to the original:

> um Ihre Sprache und andere Einstellungen speichern zu können